# Can I play iTunes U courses on the Mac?

Tags: itunes, itunes-u

I installed the iTunes U app on my iPad and subscribed to a couple of courses. Now my iPad is in repair and I wonder if I can see the courses somewhere in iTunes? When I click on iTunes U I can just see the video collections, but not the courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not today. This is similar to how iBooks also cannot (currently) be viewed on a Mac.

<sup>*(and I don't have any clue if this will ever happen, it just seems like something that* could *happen)*</sup>